# How to select XML node with different XML namespace?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML document which looks like :

```
<stReq xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <EvalRes>
    <RenDtSrc xmlns="http://fakeurl.com/somthing/facade/params">
          <ContentType>application/pdf</ContentType>
          <DocumentName>Name</DocumentName>
          <Content>Doc Content</Content>
    </RenDtSrc>
  </EvalRes>
</stReq>
```

From a asp.net application, I am trying to check if a node `<RenDtSrc>` exists in a document or not. Following is the code I am using to read XML file and node element

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("D:\\Test\\Doc1.xml");
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/stReq/EvalRes/RenDtSrc");
```

Count of `nodeList` returns zero even though there are child nodes inside it.
I think its something to do with namespace manager but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("D:\\Test\\Doc1.xml");
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("s", "http://fakeurl.com/somthing/facade/params");
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//s:RenDtSrc", nsm);
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting raw code and give some explanation as to why this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//stReq/EvalRes/node()/*");
```

Output:

```
Node [0] = {Element, Name="ContentType"}
Node [1] = {Element, Name="DocumentName"}
Node [2] = {Element, Name="Content"}
```